# Vlookup in VBA via 'result'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a Vlookup in VBA for a value in column D, ( it changes every cell) to match the values in column A on a different Tab, and to return the values in Column E that match the same value/row in column D. Why does the code below not work:

```
result = [VLOOKUP(Detail - All!D2,WOs to Del!A:A,1,false)]
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for this. I will review and make more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info....   What error message, are you sure there's a match?

Your missing apostrophes around 'sheet names', start there.  If you still bonk out then give us more information.

You can get error 2042 if your data doesn't actually have a match.

You could be getting a compile error from Option Explicit if "result" isn't declared.

But maybe you have "result" declared as a range and you're getting run time error 91.

I could go on, but really what's the point.  You didn't share the information we  need to identify everything that's broken.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will review and make question more clear.